# Why am I getting EOF when the end of the file is not reached yet?

Tags: c, file, stdin

I'm making a C program on Windows that makes an exact copy of another file. It works perfectly when I use it on a file I made myself that contains 8192 'A' characters, or just any text file, but not when I try to copy the .exe itself or a .png image
I get EOF always at the same position (usually 4096) in the files I want to copy (even though the end of the file is clearly not reached yet when I compare the EOF position with the file size).

Here is the program I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // open src file and get its size

    if(argc != 2)
        return 1;

    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(src == NULL)
        return 2;

    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    int file_size = ftell(src);
    rewind(src);


    // make destination file

    FILE *dst = fopen("copy", "w");


    // copy content of src in dst 1 byte at a time
    uint8_t byte = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < file_size; i++){

        // if eof or whatever for whatever reason
        if(fread(&byte, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, src) != 1){

            /*
            should I move the cursor myself if I get EOF?
            i mean the copy is already trash so it doesn't matter am i right c
            */

            byte = 0;
        }
        fwrite(&byte, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, dst);
    }

    // usually says 4096
    printf("%ld\n", ftell(src));

    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I know "fread() != 1" doesn't necessarily mean EOF but when I test "feof(src) != 0" inside the "if(fread(...) != 0)" it is in fact true.

So my questions are, "why do I get EOF before the end of the files I want to copy?", and "how would I go about copying a file in C?”

Comment: Are you running on a dos/Windows computer?

Comment: @wildplasser Yes on windows 10

Comment: It's been a while since I used those functions but I think it has to do with you treating everything as text files when you read and write. Try opening the files in binary mode, like fopen("copy", "wb") .

Comment: If the file is opened in Windows in text mode, the value `0x1A` (Ctrl-Z) is treated as EOF. The default translation mode is obtained from the global variable `_fmode`. It will also translate CRLF pairs to a single byte.

Comment: Have you tried feof(3)? https://linux.die.net/man/3/feof

Comment: Open the files in binary mode: `fopen(filename, "rb")` and `fopen(filename, "wb")`. Notice the `b`.

Comment: Okay I didn't know binary mode wasn't the default mode but that was it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // open src file and get its size

    if(argc != 3) // <<-- HERE
        return 1;

    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); // <<-- HERE

    if(src == NULL)
        return 2;

    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    int file_size = ftell(src);
    rewind(src);


    // make destination file

    FILE *dst = fopen("copy", "wb"); // <<-- HERE


    // copy content of src in dst 1 byte at a time
    uint8_t byte = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < file_size; i++){

        // if eof or whatever for whatever reason
        if(fread(&byte, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, src) != 1){

            /*
            should I move the cursor myself if I get EOF?
            i mean the copy is already trash so it doesn't matter am i right c
            */

            byte = 0;
        }
        fwrite(&byte, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, dst);
    }

    // usually says 4096
    printf("%ld\n", ftell(src));

    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);

    return 0;
    }
```